# Cocoa Autosizing for custom views

Tags: cocoa, view, autosize

I am using [this preference window class](http://moapp.tumblr.com/post/732365249/cocoa-preference-window-for-the-lazy-ones). It has a contentView with several subviews. How do I add autosizing to them? Just selecting autosizing options in Xcode 4 doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: set all autosize options for main content view  to true and adjust for subviews.